# JQuery, el render de mi datatable no cambia el id del item al eliminarlo

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

Estoy obteniendo registros desde una API y los muestro en un grid DataTable

[image: itemAeliminar]

Y con un enpoint estoy actualizando un estatus para que ya no se vean en el grid , paso el mouse sobre el icono de eliminar y me trae los ids correctos y solo me cambia el estatus y desaparece del grid una vez, la segunda vez que lo hago sigue trayendo el id anterior pero cuando recargo la página y vuelvo a cambiarlo otro estatus solo lo hace una vez y así sucesivamente, no logro ver que es lo que me falta para que me pase eso.

Código para dibujar el grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';

$('#employeeServicesRequests-datatable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/Controller',
        dataSrc: 'services'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'title', orderable: true },
        {
            data: 'id', orderable: false, targets: 0,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var returnValue = `<a href="#" class="action-icon view" data-id="${data}"><i class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a>` +
                    `<a href="#" class="action-icon edit" data-id="${data}"><i class="mdi mdi-square-edit-outline"></i></a>` +
                    `<a href="/Controller/Delete/${data}" class="action-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"> <i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a>`;
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
    ]
});

});
```

Código para eliminar el registro:

```
$confirmDelete.on('click', '.btn-delete', function (e) {
    debugger;
    var url = $(this).data('url');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        error: () => $.Notification.error("Error: Try again"),
        success: () => {    
            $confirmDelete.modal("toggle");
            $dataTable.DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    });
});

$confirmDelete.on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-delete').attr("data-url", $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href"));
});
```

El endpoint para cambiar status es de tipo GET:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString()))
        {
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Services/Delete/{id}");
            var item = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterServiceDTO>(response));

            if (item != null)
                return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error" });

    }
```

Se queda guardado el ultimo id pero no logro que lo haga las veces que sea necesario y no solo una vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que noto es que usas `GET` en las operaciones, recuerda que el get cachea, con lo cual ejecuta la primer operacion pero la siguiente la tomara del cache del browser sin ir al servidor

Recomendaria que cambies la operacion a el `verbo http DELETE`

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<JsonResult> Delete(string id)
{
   //codigo
}
```

desde el codigo cliente seria

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: url,
    error: () => $.Notification.error("Error: Try again"),
    success: () => {    
        $confirmDelete.modal("toggle");
        $dataTable.DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }
});
```

solo cambias el `type`

Tambien deberias aplicarlo al servicio

```
var response = await client.GetDeleteAsync($"api/Services/Delete/{id}");
```

analiza como lo explica el articulo

[HttpDelete Method In ASP.NET Web API - Part Six](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/httpdelete-method-in-asp-net-web-api-part/)

usa los verbos http de forma correcta en cada operacion

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, lo tendré que cambiar